# Filter and compare with UTC time

Tags: python

i want to run a code that starts from 10:00:00 from Monday(UTC time) till 20:00:00 Friday(UTC time).

Firstly, i used utcnow() function to get hours and minutes

```
from datetime import datetime
UTC_time = datetime.utcnow()
current_UTC_time = (datetime.utcnow()).time()
```

Then tried to extract week name

```
UTC_week_name = (datetime.utcnow()).strftime('%A')
```

After that unable to devise any comparison?

Comment: You might want to look in to "cron job" if you want to schedule a script to run regularly on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Update

If you want to run every two hours starting from Monday 10 AM til Friday midnight then you can split this into two cron jobs.

One for Monday: `0 0 10/2 ? * MON *`

Another one for Tues-Fri: `0 0 0/2 ? * TUE,WED,THU,FRI *`

This [website](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) can help you create cron expressions if you need it.
I hope it helps.

---

The approach you are using is very inefficient as the python process to check the time will be getting executed at every moment.

There is a system-utility known as **cron jobs**. You can use it to schedule jobs. [This](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) link provides a detailed expression. 
For your job, the following would be the cron-job expression.

```
0 0 10 ? * MON *
```

Comment: what if , i have to run at every 2 hours post 10:00:00 AM  monday till 10:00:00 PM Friday  of every week ???

Comment: Updated the answer.